# how to convert date object in 14 Dec 2020 from database in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

When I tried to convert 2020-12-14 to 14 Dec 2020 by using
1st Method

```
<small>{item.date}</small>
```

2nd Method

```
{new Date(item.date).toLocaleString()}
```

then I got below output

```
2020-12-14
```

```
12/14/2020, 5:30:00 AM
```

Is there any way to convert the date format from 2020-12-14 to 14 Dec 2020.? in reactjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small modification to this elegant answer by [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39103318/10949543) splits the `toString` date string into an array and formats it into the result you want. Check the code below:

```js
const date = new Date(2020, 11, 14).toString().split(" ");
// ["Mon", "Dec", "14", "2020", "14:05:53", "GMT+0100", "(Central", "European", "Standard", "Time)"]
console.log(date[2] + " " + date[1] + " " + date[3]);
// 14 Dec 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

using moment package

```
moment(moment('2020-11-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD')).format('DD MMM YYYY');
```